# How to code an sql string in vba to use greater than or less than symbols in my MS Access form, when searching for dates in one textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list of records that I can search by inputting various date or selecting between dates, and using sql script it returns the results. But I would like to know how can I use greater than symbol in the date textbox and have sql script recognize it and return dates greater than for example ">7/1/2021"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `WHERE DateField > #7/1/2021#`

Comment: `WHERE DateField > 2021-07-01`

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would do this is to use a combo box that has the various operators (<=,<,=,>,>=) stored as a value list, in addition to the text box that has the date. This is a good idea as you limit the choices that the user can make for the comparison, and you still get to use the input mask for the date field in the combo box.

You can then concatenate the comparison and the date to a SQL string that provides the search. Something like:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    Const JetDateFmt = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#;;;\N\u\l\l"
    strSQL = "SELECT * " _
        & " FROM TB_Edditions " _
        & " WHERE ED_Start_Date " & Me!cboOperator & Format(Me!txtDate, JetDateFmt) _
        & " ORDER BY ID ASC;"
    Me!lstResult.RowSource = strSQL
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmDateSearch!cmdSearch_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

In this instance I am using the SQL created to populate a list box. You will note that I am forcing the date entered to be in a specific format, so that it is interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you are invoking the sql query and that matters, but one approach is you can access public functions anywhere in access.  So if you have public functions GetOperator and GetDate you can either pass them as parameters to the sql query, bind them to the sql query directly, or use them in the designer:
For a case like < or > and a date you want to validate the textbox entry first.  I tried to validate using the textbox validation rule but apparently this case was too complicated.  I ended up having to use the textbox BeforeUpdate Event.

```
Private Sub txtFilter_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'text box name is txtFilter
If isValidOperator(Me.txtFilter) And isValidDate(Me.txtFilter) Then
Cancel = False
setmysearchcriteria = Me.txtFilter
Else
MsgBox "Search criteria must be in the form of operatordate such as <4/12/21", vbOKOnly
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
Public Function isValidOperator(strText As String) As Boolean
Dim operator As String
operator = Left(strText, 1)
If operator = ">" Or operator = "<" Then
SetOperator (operator)
isValidOperator = True
Else
isValidOperator = False
End If
End Function
Private Function isValidDate(strDate As String) As Boolean
strDate = Mid(strDate, 2)
If IsDate(strDate) Then
SetDate (strDate)
isValidDate = True
Else
isValidDate = False
End If
End Function
```

Here is the code for the public functions serving as synthetic properties.  Just pass the Get functions as parameters or invoke them as functions directly in the sql.

```
Private strMyDate As String
Private myoperator As String
Public Function SetDate(strDate As String) As Boolean
strMyDate = "#" & strDate & "#"
SetDate = True
End Function
Public Function GetDate() As String

GetDate = strMyDate
End Function

Public Function SetOperator(operator As String) As Boolean
myoperator = operator
SetOperator = True
End Function
Public Function GetOperator() As String
GetOperator = myoperator
End Function
```

In most case you will want to trigger your sql in the textbox AfterUpdate event.  For instance  Changes to the form your textbox is in will not show if you trigger your sql in the BeforeUpdate event.

```
Private Sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate()
'trigger your sql here instead of setting the filter
Me.Filter = "ADate " & GetOperator & " " & GetDate
Debug.Print Me.Filter
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Like @braX said, enclose your date literals inside two # characters..

Comment: doesn't answer the question